# Рефлексия - как передать в параметры конструктора массив

Tags: java, рефлексия

```
public List createFloor(Point[] points, Class<? extends List> listClass) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        try {
            return listClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{Point[].class}).newInstance(points); // хочу здесь создать объект от массива points
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

Есть классы:
FunctionPoint реализует интерфейс Point, ArrayList, LinkedList реализуют List

Comment: можете на словах сказать что вы хотите сделать, из кода я не понимаю что должно произойти

Comment: у `ArrayList` нет конструктора, принимающего массив, поэтому - никак

Comment: Такой конструктор есть у ArrayList

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov я хочу получить объект типа Class для моего массива points

Comment: newInstance используйте а дальше заполняйте его элементами из массива. @zRrr прав, у вас ограничение по wildcard'ам для потомков List но это не обязывает их иметь конструктор принимающий массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{Point[].class}).newInstance(new Object[] {points});
```

newInstance принимает массив аргументов, когда вы передаете туда массив он думает что это массив параметров, чтобы явно указать, что массив это 1 параметр, нужно передать массив объектов, в котором элемент ваш массив.

Comment: работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Class[]{Point[].class}
```

Вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса Class, вроде как у него нет публичных конструкторов.

```
return listClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{Point[].class}).newInstance(points);
```

в классе List нет конструкторов которые будут принимать объект типа Class, который вы пытаетесь создать

---

В рефлексии я не силен, но попробуйте так

```
listClass.getConstructor(Point[].class).newInstance(points)
```

Comment: getConstructor() принимает либо 1 параметр либо массив параметров, т.е. мой код ничем не отличается от вашего.Ошибка в том, что я не знаю как получить объект класса Class для массива points

Comment: мой от вашего отличается, тем что я не пытаюсь создать объект Class. т.к. это не возможно

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую сделать так:

```
public static <T extends List<Point>> List<Point> createList(Point[] points, Class<T> type) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        List<Point> list = type.newInstance();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(points));
        return list;
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

А использовать его можно будет следующим образом:

```
List<Point> list = createList(new Point[]{new Point(), new Point()}, ArrayList.class);
```